# spring boot project domain and sub-domain

Tags: spring, .htaccess, spring-boot

I'm New on Java and Spring. I'm trying to migrate a product that has a particular issue.

It's a web site that has sub-domains that work together.

api.mydomain.com has the actions for the working site and externals calls
admin.mydomain.com do the admin operations for the site, like ad news, events, banners, etc.
www.mydomain.com is the default site, product of api and admin actions.

How can i create the project to build it as one package?! I need to create 3 projects?! If so, how can i have access for each other resources?!

Comment: Do you want to have a single executable or have a different executable for each domain?

Comment: It'll be nice has just one executable, to make just one deploy, but i think it's better to manager one executable for each sub-domain, but i need access each other foles and don't have a clue how to do it

Answer (score 0):

### [Multi-Module Maven Project](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

You can build multiple applications (web, api, etc.) at once using a Multi-Module Maven Project structure.  You'll have a Parent project that will reference the Children projects and build each one in the order you specify.

If you're completely new to Maven, read this first:

[**Building Java Projects with Maven**](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/)

You're question is actually quite complicated if you need to think about CORS, API Gateway, Proxies, URL Pattern Matching, etc.  Thankfully there are a lot of solutions in the Spring ecosystem to help with this.

**[Spring Cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/)**

Comment: Thanks I'll check!! I'm having problems to find Spring material that works and i'm looking for a user group.

I've tryed Facebook Social Media samples and it didn't worked

Comment: @RafaelBandeiraRodrigues This is a great resource for learning Spring: https://spring.io/guides  As far as User Groups, your mileage will vary based on location.